# How to invoke F# auto-completion in Emacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, f#, f#-3.0

I installed FSharp 3.1, Emacs 24 and fsharp-mode of emacs. Howerver the auto-completion feature (complete-at-point) didn't work. I followed all the instructions here https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/blob/master/emacs/README.md and added fsautocomplete.exe to my $PATH .

But it still didn't work.

PS:
I failed in Debian sid, Ubuntu Trusty and Mac 10.9.

Comment: "On Unix-like systems, you must use the `--readline-` flag to ensure F# Interactive will work correctly with Emacs. Typically `fsi` and `fsc` are invoked through the shell scripts `fsharpi` and `fsharpc`." Did you do this, too?

Comment: I did, but it seems that fsharpbinding doesn't use fsi or fsc to implement the auto-completion feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the author. In order to have autocomplete in fsharp-mode, you must either be editing a script (.fsx) file, or a normal (.fs) file that is associated with a project (.fsproj) file.

If a .fs file is opened and no other project has already been loaded, then fsharp-mode will look for and load a .fsproj in the current and enclosing directories. This can be done manually using <kbd>C-c C-p</kbd>. At this point autocompletion will be available in all .fs files mentioned in the project.

If a project has not been loaded, then no autocompletion will be available in .fs files.

I tried to make this clear in the README.md. I'll have a look updating it, and trying to give feedback in the interface as to why autocompletion is not available.

Comment: I have next error when run `mono fsautocomplete.exe` : Invalid type Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.SourceCodeServices.FSharpProjectFileInfo for instance field FSharp.InteractiveAutocomplete.Main+files@464:p Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'FSharp.InteractiveAutocomplete.Main+files@464' from assembly 'fsautocomplete, Version=0.18.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at FSharp.InteractiveAutocomplete.Main.entry (System.String[] args)

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1)

Answer (score 0):

The author gave me the solution that the .fs file must be in the same directory with the .fsproject relating to it.